# error Autoprefixer sublime text 3. How to solve this problem?

Tags: sublimetext3, autoprefixer

error: Autoprefixer
Error: Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
npx browserslist@latest --update-db

Why you should do it regularly:
https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#browsers-data-updating

I performed this command, but everything is the same, the same error comes out

Comment: Did it show the packages updating when you ran that command? Have you restarted Sublime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `C:\Users\This PC\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\Autoprefixer`,
open terminal and run:

```
npm update
```

and:

```
npx browserslist@latest --update-db
```